# How to download a website page after waiting or everything is loaded

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, html, firefox-extensions

i'm trying to accomplish this :

Trying to download some Page HTMLs. but i've to wait ! to get everything loaded . (the website have to load all the ressources files so it takes time) .

How to wait then download these HTML PAGE ? i didn't found any grabber website that can do this job 
Please Any Suggestion ?

you think that this need something like webbrowser in DELPHI ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firefox add on named [DownloadThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/). You can grab entire webpage and its hyperlinks. Just give right click on the webpage or paste that webpage link at download field.

[image]

Comment: I KNOW DOWNLOADTHEMALL . the problem of DTM : is that it sends requests and save the html directly , it didn't wait to page to be fully loaded . i want to wait(that the page get loads) before download the page to html .

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to be rude, but I can't understand what you're asking.  I have two possible answers, depending on how I have mis-understood your question.

=====

For years, web browsers have intentionally downloaded and displayed web pages and objects bit-by-bit, as each bit is downloaded.  This prevents the user from staring at a blank page wondering if the web page is loading or not.  The user sees progress, and the user gets the appearance of faster web browsing.

You want to undo this feature, and simply stare at a blank page until the entire web page has loaded, before anything gets displayed.  I'm not even sure if a browser **can** do that anymore, but perhaps there is an option to be found.  If so, I wouldn't know what it is, and I can't imagine a scenario where it would be useful.

=====

You want the browser to somehow expect that you are going to go to a particular web page, and it should pre-download all of the slower parts in advance before you decide to download the final "piece" that displays the web page.

I don't see how you can expect that to happen.  The web browser can't know what to download until you tell it, and the web browser can't know what other pieces need to be downloaded until that web page tells it.

Some items can be cached locally, but if nothing else, the web browser needs to determine if the cache is still valid or out of date.

Comment: Thank you very much i think i found a solution , but not too much fast .. but its good , what i want is saving html files from URLS . but not directly . i've to wait  Some minutes to get the PAGE CHARGED ,( fully LOADED) then download it .